# How do I customize Gnome screen shield / curtain / login screen appearance?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, screen-lock, dconf, appearance

Gnome desktop seems configurable in various ways: in "*Gnome settings*", with [gnome-extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/), [`gnome-tweak-tool`](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/GnomeTweakTool?action=show&redirect=GnomeTweakTool), [`gsettings`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gsettings-tool.html) or [`dconf-editor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf).

However, apart from [this procedure to change the login screen background](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM#Log-in_screen_background_image), which involves a little bit of glib compiling, I have found no way to customize the appearance of:

- the login screen (font, position, color and size of the login boxes)
- shield screen *aka* lock screen *aka* curtain (font, position, color, format and size of the clock, displayed messages, *etc.*)

I understand that Gnome philosophy is not to allocate much resource in tweaky-tweak-tweaking-tweakable stuffs. But I am suprised that such basic and harmless properties of these screens seem so difficult to access.

Is there a way I can access and tweak login / shield screen organization properties?
Are they hardcoded or is it just a matter of sneaking into a small `curtain.xml` or `loginscreen.json`?
Do I need to get into the sources and compile gnome myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ubuntu

I use ubuntu 18.04, (also done this in 17.10) and as of how **@cezanee-vahid** said, you can find the CSS file here: **`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css`** and by changing this file you don't need to restart **`gnome`** or do anything else, they will be changed by locking computer (or better to say will be reloaded).

so for changing clock size you only need to change **`font-size`** and **`font-weight`** for **`.screen-shield-clock-time`** class.

also for if you want to get ride off that arrows in the bottom of the screen just set **`0`** for **`height`** and **`width`** of **`.screen-shield-arrows Gjs_Arrow`** CSS selector. setting **`0`** for **`font-size`** of **`.screen-shield-clock-date`** will do the same for Date.

## Arch

I'm not an Arch or even Arch-based distro user, but after reading [ArchWiki about GDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GDM) it seems like you need to compile source files for GDM after changing them. also, the **`gdm3.css`** file in Arch is named **`gnome-shell.css`**

so in conclusion, these spets are needed to change GDM theme in Arch:

1. extracting the current GDM theme
2. creating a **`gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml`** file for the selected image files
3. changing **`gnome-shell.css`** file as you wish!
4. compiling the new GDM theme you have created
5. replacing files under **`/usr/share/gnome-shell`**
6. restating **`gdm.service`**

the ArhcWiki above have explained these steps detailed.

Comment: Thank you for these precisions. Unfortunately, I can find no `gdm3.css` file on my system (this is archlinux speaking). The closest I have found are two files at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/{gnome-classic.css,gnome-classic-high-contrast.css}`, which do contain the properties you suggest. However, any change I make to these files seem to have no effect even after I restart my computer :\ Can I ask you where you have found these informations? Is there any official documentation about these files?

Comment: @iago-lito i have updated the answer and think that it should work, I'm looking forward to your reply! and also for ubuntu i just found these things by playing around with `gdm3.css` file.

Comment: Great! The compilation was the step I've missed. Cheers :)

Comment: As suggested [there](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1479239), just type `rt` in the `<Alt+F2>` dialog box to restart the theme instead of restarting the whole `gdm.service`.. it's easier and it doesn't require superuser permissions :)

Comment: that's great! thank you for feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a little too late but you can customize the values in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css` and that does the trick. Just find the `screen-shield-clock` class and make your changes. One simple thing I did to make it a little nicer is set the `font-weight` to `300` and it improves the look a million times.

Comment: Hey, not bad. This could help a lot, cheers :) Have you found any piece of documentation regarding the meaning of these values? I couldn't find any. Also, do I need to restart or recompile something? I couldn't get any of my changes happening. The file I've found is called `gnome-classic.css`.

Comment: Huh. Perhaps in that same directory you can try tweaking `gnome-shell.css` or `ubuntu.css`

Comment: Nope, doesn't have any :\ Is there any doc about this somewhere?